# PivotChart: Can't move title without activating the chart

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a little macro in Excel 2010 to move the chart title of a pivot chart, and I can get it to work using a method that activates the chart and selects the chart's title. Here is that code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    'On Error GoTo GetOut
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    If ActiveChart.HasTitle = True Then
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
            With Selection
                .Left = 311.982
                .Top = 9.559
            End With
    End If

GetOut:
    ActiveSheet.Range("M21").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

But I would like to avoid activating the object, so I wrote this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim empChart As ChartObject

'On Error GoTo GetOut
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set empChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
If empChart.HasTitle = True Then
    With empChart.ChartTitle
        .Left = 311.982
        .Top = 9.559
    End With
End If

GetOut:
ActiveSheet.Range("M21").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

But this gives me runtime error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method. I can't figure out why for the life of me. I'm not very good so it is probably something silly, but any help would be much appreciated

Comment: `empChart` is a `ChartObject`, a `ChartObject` has a `Chart`, and the `Chart` has `.HasTitle` and `.ChartTitle`. So you need `empChart.Chart.HasTitle` and `empChart.Chart.ChartTitle`. Easiest fix is to `Dim empChart As Chart`, then `Set empChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart`. Then the rest will work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A worksheet `ChartObject` has a child `Chart` object: you can access this directly using (eg)

```
Dim cht As Chart
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
```

Then you can operate on `cht` directly instead of using ActiveChart.

Comment: That did the trick.Thanks a bunch! I knew it was something stupid. If I had enough rep to vote for you I would.